# how can i optimize my web Scraping script run on deferent OS

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a script that gets some data from a website, and it runs smoothly on my local machine. But when I try to run it on a another machine with a different OS it throws this error:

> ~/test/Zawali-effect-main# node scrapper.js
>
> [*] Launching Script
>
> [?] Searching for Latest Match ID
>
> [+] Latest Match ID # NaN
>
> [?] Searching for the Earliest Match from 28 Days Ago
>
> [?] Initial Guess
>
> Jump back 3200000 IDs
>
> [-] Bad ID. Shifting by 1
>
> /root/test/Zawali-effect-main/node_modules/core/lib/JsPath.ts:112
>
> **InjectedScriptError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null**
> at JsPath.runJsPath (/root/test/Zawali-effect-main/node_modules/core/lib/JsPath.ts:112:13)
> at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
> at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)

And again it works fine on my **Windows 10** local machine but it doesn't on **Ubuntu 20.04**.

Comment: Do you have the same folder on you `ubuntu` server?

Comment: yes i do . in fact i cloned the Repo straight from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

...means that the element you expect to be present on the page and want to process doesn't exist. I'd bet that the whole page is different from what you're usually get.

If you've deployed your script on a server with a cloud provider it just may be so that its IP is blocked or marked as suspicious. The target site may also change its content even based on the OS string in the browser user agent.

Try to make a screenshot and log the HTML of the page you're getting on the server, is probably is not the same as on the local Windows machine.